# Should I ask again something that's been asked a long time ago?

Tags: discussion, old-questions, old-answers

Somebody [asked this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5543360) five years ago. Something new may have appeared since then. How should I ask for new, up-to-date answers?

Comment: Such question would be OT nowadays anyway. Policies had  changed over time.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ Actually I was surprised to find it on SO. Anyway, where can I ask that now ? I thought of Games or Programmers...

Comment: Elsewhere, not here. Game developers rarely use _[tag:brainfuck]_ language BTW.

Comment: Software Recommendations maybe but double check with them.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ Arqade, not game development, sorry

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ignoring the (now closed) off-topic example and answering the more general question, no, you should not ask a question again just because it was asked a long time ago. People are still free to add new answers to on-topic questions when things change. If you find a question that needs new answers, you should add a bounty to it to attract attention. Barring that, you could also post a link to the question in a relevant chat room, or link to it on social media to get more people to add new answers.

Comment: It got closed as a result of this very question (:

Comment: Will the bounty award bring a new answer nearer the top in the default display order?  There are often correct answers slumming down in the low-vote underworld overshadowed by what sounded good to a lot of people in the first hours of the question.  I wonder how many people see them.

Comment: @sh1 No, only votes will make an answer rise to the top. A bounty just gets them noticed through more page views. People who are actually looking for an answer will see them if the top answers aren't that helpful. Having them at the bottom of the page (hopefully only temporarily) is still better than having them on a different page entirely.

Comment: Sometimes good, old answers come with caveats, or are merely "the best that can be done in this situation", or even "no, that's unsupported" and they appear to be the final word on the matter, except that the situation has changed.  Sometimes all the popular answers are wrong but in a subtle way, or not best practice, and the comment pointing out the issue in the top answer is hidden under "read more comments".  There are lots of reasons to stop reading before you find to the canonical solution.  If people had time to read a lot they'd probably read the manual.

Comment: @sh1 People who stop reading before they get to the real solution don't really have a problem.

Comment: It's perhaps more accurate to say they don't _know_ they have a problem.  So long as it's only hobbyists who don't deploy what they learn on SO, I guess that's just fine.

Comment: @sh1 I don't think we're talking about the same thing at all.