# What should I do to have an updated answer to an old question?

Tags: support, old-questions, outdated-information

There is a question I wanted to ask, and [it was already asked](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15435121/what-is-the-maximum-size-of-webrtc-data-channel-messages). So I read it, but the answer is 3 years old and I don't know if it still up-to-date.

So I posted a comment to know what is up, but there is no reaction a couple of days later.

Should I remake the question or what?

Comment: Related: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/330546/2675154

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should not remake the question, as it will be closed as a duplicate. You might want to post the same comment on the answer; the answerer isn't notified yet.

If that doesn't help, you can place a bounty on the question.